# PowerMock throwing null pointer exception at queue.add method

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

I am using Powermock to unit test a class.

The Class has a queue of List of objects as private member. 
I am using PowerMock `createPartialMock` to partially mock two of the methods (say A and B) and then explicitly calling method C and then verify.

```
Class Sample {
    Queue<List> q;

    public C() {  
        A(); 
        B(); 
        q.add(List);
    }

    private A() {}
    private B() {}
}

Class Test {
    void testSomeMethod() {
        Sample mock = PowerMock.createPartialMock(Sample.class, "A", "B");
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(Sample.class, A).thenReturn("true");
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(Sample.class, B).thenReturn("true");

        mock.C();
        PowerMock.verify(mock);
    }
}
```

Now when I run the tests, PowerMock throws exception at `q.add(List);` line.

Can anyone please point out what mistake am I making?
Do I have expect q.add() method call as well?

Comment: `q` was not initialized and throws therefore a NPE. You can inject internal state via: `Whitebox.setInternalState(mock, "q", new LinkedList<List>());` Also `q.add(List);` seems not to be valid Java as `List` is no valid instance. In addition to that, the PowerMock has an own page on how to [mock constructors](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

Comment: @RomanVottner why not do it like this
`Whitebox.setInternalState(mock, "q", new PriorityQueue<>());`
it will add any list which is subtype of 'java.util.List'

Comment: @Vihar I gave just a simple example on how to inject an object into a field of the class to testas long a the object to inject is an implementation for  `Queue<List>`. [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is just one of many things you can assign. If you prefer `PriorityQueue<>` then use it as replacement for the linked list

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow assign a value to *q* attribute of Sample class.
This can be done on constructor, by a setter method or by reflection (Whitebox class or pure Java reflection code).

If you need to check whether a item is added to q, create a mock of Queue interface.